# How to use async pipe with arrays in new Angular 17?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-pipe, angular17, async-pipe

Suppose i have this promise in my component class.

```
testAsyncNumber = new Promise(
  (res,rej)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{res([1,2,3,4,5])
  },2000);
});
```

In view template i need to get data using async pipe. I tried following approach.

```
<div>
  @for (number of (testAsyncNumber | async); track number) {
    {{ number }}
  } @empty {
    Empty list of users
  }
</div>
```

But this doesn't work. How to overcome with this issue?

Comment: What result do you get? and What behavior do you expect?

Comment: "doesn't work" is the most unhelpful symptom. Please expand

Comment: I didn't compile. Somehow with the provided answers i managed to get the data. For your reference, this was the error message i got. "[ERROR] NG8: Type '{}' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator."

Answer (score 2):

By default, TypeScript infers the type of the following Promise as `Promise<unknown>`. That's why you are getting an error. If you add explicit typing, it will resolve the issue:

```
testAsyncNumber:  Promise<Array<number>> = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    }, 2000);
});
```

**OR**

you can disable type checking on `testAsyncNumber` by adding `$any` function

```
<div>
  @for (number of $any(testAsyncNumber | async); track number) {
    {{ number }}
  } @empty {
    Empty list of users
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to utilize RxJs more:

See this on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ktwsyv)

TS variable:

```
  testAsyncNumber = from(
    new Promise<number[]>((res) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        res([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
      }, 2000);
    })
  ).pipe(startWith([-1]));
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  @for (number of (testAsyncNumber | async); track number) {
    {{ number }}
  } @empty {
    Empty list of users
  }
</div>
```